# getting rid of the planes in SliceDensityPlot3D

Tags: plotting

I have a problem I would like to make a plot of a 3D density that looks similar with SliceDensityPlot3D with "ZStackedPlanes" options but without the God awful planes that appear, keeping only the density. For example, in the code bellow

```
    SliceDensityPlot3D[
 Exp[(-((\[Eta] (a^2 + (x^2 + y^2) \[Omega]^2 + 
      2 a  \[Omega] (x Cos[(z) \[Omega]] + 
         y Sin[(z) \[Omega]])))/ (\[Omega]^2)))] //. {\[Omega] -> 2, 
   a -> 1, \[Eta] -> 1}, "ZStackedPlanes", {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 
  2}, {z, -2, 2}]
```

how could I keep that density and completely remove the planes?

Thanks

Comment: do you get what you need if you add the options `PlotRange->{0.5,1}` and `ClippingStyle->None`?

Comment: ... or,  alternatively, using the option `RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, f}, .5<f<1]`?

Comment: By adding PlotRange->{0.5,1} and ClippingStyle->None I get what I need. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can add the options `PlotRange -> {0.5, 1}` and  `ClippingStyle -> None`:

```
SliceDensityPlot3D[Exp[(-((η (a^2 + (x^2 + y^2) ω^2 + 2 a  ω (x Cos[(z) ω] + 
     y Sin[(z) ω])))/ (ω^2)))] /. {ω -> 2, a -> 1, η -> 1}, 
  "ZStackedPlanes", 
   {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2},
   PlotRange -> {0.5, 1}, ClippingStyle -> None]
```

[image]